# how to control typed text in node.js console app

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, console-application

i want to create console app and according to typed value i want to make `if , else if` control here is code;

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', function() {

  var chunk = process.stdin.read();

  if (chunk == "generate") {
    process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
  }else if(chunk === "mapping"){
    process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
  }else if(chunk === "--help"){
    process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
  }else{
    console.log("Undefined command ! please type ' --help ' to learn  commands");
  }
});
```

it is not handle if controls , else part works with any typed value. I tried to make chunk variable to string but it did not work.

**solved with ;**
https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: Moreover , typeof chunk is string :S  but if controls not working :S

Comment: solved wtih https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html